# Html cross-platform animation library

Tags: html, animation, cross-platform

I'm having a headache trying to find a cross-platform library to build some small html games
the platforms include: IE8+, FF, Chrome, Safari, Android, IOS

well I don't want to use Flash, and I can't use Flash because there is IOS anyways

first glimpse I found Kinetic.js, which appears to be really handy after trying it out, but I can not find any canvas fallbacks on IE8

second glimpse I found Raphael, which is also really good, but Android does not support SVG

I don't think jQuery animations is the right way to go, after all it's not intended for a game

so..any recommandations?

please don't tell me I have to go with writing a whole chunk of transitions myself..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you hear Android doesn't support SVG? I've looked at SVGs on my Nexus 7 plenty.

Comment: Android 2.x does not have native support for SVG

Comment: There are two libraries i know of one is [collie](http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie/performance.html?l=en) and the next is [GSAP JS](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/)

Comment: If you find helpful let me know :) Regards

Comment: Maybe a polyfill for canvas elements helps? Try http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: well...collie is kinda broken on IE 8 due to lack of transform. All I can find is a hack to get Easel.js working with ExCanvas, and there is a patched version of Crafty.js, both of which are not stable